# how to eliminate NaT values from time coords in xarray

Tags: python, datetime, python-xarray, nat

I have an xarray DataArray with time as one of the coordinates - however, some of the coordinate values are NaT.

the time coords are stored as numpy.datetime64 values.

How do I remove values corresponding to coordinates where time = NaT?

I can select the subset of the data where time = NaT using

```
data.sel(time = "NaT")
```

However, the code

```
data.sel(time != "NaT")
```

produces the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19648/1491593867.py in <module>
----> 1 wind.sel(time != "NaT")

NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

additionally, dropna methods such as

```
data.dropna(dim = "time")
#or
```

return the entire dataset without removing the NaT data .

How can I drop the data associated with NaT time values?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "remove"? if it's a coordinate, you would have to remove all dependent elements as well, no?

Comment: does `data.sel(time=data.time.notnull())` work?

Comment: in your example, `data.sel(time != "NaT")` is trying to reference a variable `time` which indeed doesn't exist. `data.sel(time=(data.time != "NaT"))` might work, except that NaNs never compare True - that is, `NaT != NaT`. So using `data.time.notnull()` is probably your best bet

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 'time' it's a coordinate, not a dimension of your DataSet.

I used two forms and both worked with my DataSet.
[with 'NaT'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsUky.png)

1. Using xarray.DataArray.dropna()

   ds.time.dropna(dim='trajectory',how='any')

[After removing 'NaT'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLSlP.png)

2. Transforming to dataframe and using dropna()

   df = ds.isel(trajectory=1).to_dataframe()

   df.dropna(axis=0,how='any')

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)